# Office 365 API for Global Address List?

Tags: ms-office, preview

I'm experimenting with the API for Office 365... I can see the results of this query okay:

https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts?$select=DisplayName,EmailAddress1,Birthday,Categories

It shows the contacts stored against a certain user.

Is there an equivalent function for querying the contacts that are stored in the "Global Address List? The one you get to if you go to the "Admin" link and then the "Users and Groups" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the Office 365 API is based on the User giving the App consent to particular permissions. The Global Address List is not one of these right now. if this is something you are interested in, I would highly recommend submitted this to UserVoice where our engineering team is monitoring http://aka.ms/OfficeDevFeedback

Answer (score 2):

Azure Active Directory Graph API will provide what you are looking for.

MSDN reference - "[Get Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151605.aspx)"

Newer documentation is at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog